# Performing a second replace in backreference for a regexp

Tags: regex, backreference

I have lines from a web page of the form

```
<a href="url with spaces">description with spaces</a>
```

which I want to convert to a csv format

```
"url%20%with%20spaces","description with spaces"
```

to feed into a mediawiki page that expects external links to be [url%20%with%20spaces description with spaces] (and I don't want that page to be cluttered with #rreplace)

```
sed -Ee 's`.*href="(.*)">(.*)</a>.*`"\1","\2"`'
```

can split the url, but I can't see an easy way to do a further substitution of space with %20 in just \1 without affecting \2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using GNU `awk` like

```
awk -F'href="|">|</a>' '{gsub(/ /, "%20",$2);print "\""$2"\",\""$3"\""}'
```

See the [`awk` demo](https://ideone.com/kkd2kW) online.

The field separator pattern here is `href="|">|</a>`, it matches either `href="`, or `">`, or ` to split the line into fields.

The second field needs additional processing, so `gsub(/ /, "%20",$2)` is used to replace each space with `%20` substring. The updated Field 2 and Field 3 are used to form the resulting output.